# Why is Immortan Joe called that?

Tags: names, mad-max-fury-road

In Mad Max: Fury Road, the evil boss is named "Immortan Joe". I understand that the "Joe" part comes from his original name, Joe Moore, but what's "Immortan"? Is it just a verbal gag by creator Miller, or does it actually mean anything?

Comment: [Someone asked the same question on Quora](https://www.quora.com/In-Mad-Max-Fury-Road-why-is-Immortan-Joe-called-Immortan-instead-of-the-more-logical-Immortal-Is-there-a-hidden-meaning-for-this)

Comment: \*chanting\* Im-mor-tan … Im-mor-tan …

Comment: I thought they were saying "Immortal Joe", which I totally attributed to him clearly living longer than he should have.

Comment: I believe it’s short for Immortan Joseph.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Immortan = Immortal Man

[image]

From an interview with **Hugh Keays-Byrne**, the actor who plays Immortan Joe:

> **Q:** What is an “Immortan?”
>
> **KEAYS-BYRNE:** “Immortal Man.” So the cult, the idea: you can’t kill me. I’m here forever, and I just keep going in this mayhem that we are surrounded with. This natural world which is falling apart, I am able to control. Out of the ashes you will rise, with my help.

([Source](http://www.craveonline.com/site/857843-exclusive-interview-mad-max-villain-immortan-joe#V3JwQwrakCLSqjc2.99))

Comment: (Facepalms self) Well, that's what I get for asking I guess.

Comment: @einpoklum The right answer?  I never would have guessed something so straightforward.  It was clear that it was related to immortality, but beyond that, who knew?